# Jenkins(Hudson) SVN Updating ALL files instead of Updated

Tags: ftp, hudson, jenkins

Im using Jenkins to upload files to the FTP server.
Ive installed 'Publish Over FTP'. when i run the build i can see on the output it has update the new commits but it it uploads ALL files to the ftp instead of just the updated files.

im using 'Use svn update as much as possible'

```
Updating http://10.1.1.121/svn/woman_legal/trunk
A         app/webroot/pdf
A         app/webroot/pdf/Turkish.pdf
AU        app/webroot/pdf/Chinese.pdf
AU        app/webroot/pdf/Vietnamese.pdf
A         app/webroot/pdf/Arabic.pdf
AU        app/webroot/pdf/Spanish.pdf
U         app/views/elements/frontend/topbar.ctp
```

this is the console ouput before FTP starts.

Answer (score 0):

The setting "Use SVN update as much as possible" is only for the SVN plugin, the publish over ftp Plugin cannot access its value.
Publish Over FTP does not even know that the files you are sending were checked out from an SVN repository, they could as well be generated as part of the build or copied there using some other plugin.
I am not aware of any way that would allow to select (and publish) only the updated source files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution by which people use a diff tool such as Beyond Compare (through md5 checksums on the filesets) to check which files should be transferred.  I'm sorry I don't have the code to share here, however, it shouldn't be difficult to add the fileset check process as a post-build step and then alter the publish over FTP to Jenkins as a plugin.  We've begun working on this and will post back if/when we finish!